# Comparing to booleans gives false when they have the same value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement an audit table using Entity Framework core 2.0. However, all the fields are being saved, not just the edited ones. I thought I could do a simple if statement. If the old value is not equal to the new value then it is a changed value.

However, this is not working for booleans. Two true booleans are coming out as not equal.

Here is my very simple code:

```
                        if (property.OriginalValue != property.CurrentValue)
                        { 
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        }
```

[image]

Hopefully, you can see in the image that both `OldValues` and `NewValues` are true but it drops into the `if` statement when it shouldn't. I would like an `if` statement that compares strings, ints, booleans etc if possible.

Comment: Can you show us in the debugger what the two values are set to at the time of the `if` statement?

Comment: What is the value of `property.OriginalValue`? `property.OriginalValue.GetType`? `property.CurrentValue`? `property.CurrentValue.GetType`? _Don't guess, please debug and check._

Comment: @mjwills Guess they are an object with a type of bool (see new image in editted post). That is the cause of my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to do with the fact that property.OriginalValue and property.CurrentValue are 2 objects. Since the 2 don't reference the same object they are never equal.  Try comparing using .ToString() or something like: property.IsModified

Comment: property.IsModified was always true for some reason even if they were not modified which is why i couldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this line:

```
if (((property.OriginalValue != null) ? property.OriginalValue.ToString() : "" ) != ((property.CurrentValue != null) ? property.CurrentValue.ToString() : ""))
```